# Issue with Open Console button from Db2 on Cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

When I click on the Open Console button from by Db2 resource on the IBM Cloud, I am getting the following error:

Error 401: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 401

I am logged into my Cloud account, so I'm not sure why there is an authorization error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be addressed to the vendor support.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Console button uses SSO for authentication. I can't diagnose why you're getting a 401 in this case, but you can instead try logging in using the given username and password. You can find this by navigating to the Service Credentials tab on the left side of the service instance page, clicking New Credential, clicking Add in the dialog box, and clicking View credentials to expand the JSON contents. You can find your username and password there and use them to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only way how I have resolved this is just by deleting this Db2 service and creating the new one.

Be sure that the location chosen while creating the new Db2 service is DALLAS.